# laravel 5 all::() method ALWAYS 500s on large queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been trying to find constant workarounds for my data issues with Laravel 5 in a project I'd like to migrate and I can't seem to find a satisfactory answer as to why Laravel 5 will always throw a 500 error whenever I try to use the "::all()" method on a model. I've implemented the "chunk" method but I am not getting result sets that I want and really I'm in essence wanting a simple "select * from" so I feel it shouldn't be this big a deal.

It will work if the result set is less than a few thousand, anything over and it kills the program. I have my php.ini set to allow 1024M, the query has no joins but just in case, max_execution_time is at 1000, it isn't a post but max_post_value is 1024M -- what gives? Surely Laravel CAN support bringing back large datasets?

Comment: You'll exhaust memory when you create collection of thousands models, just use raw query and do it without eloquent. Or chunk really.

Comment: even the DB raw query does it. This is madness, my raw php app was able to with these data sets.

Comment: Show us the content of your model and your table structure

Comment: That's just the cost of using tools that make your life easier. You still can use `chunk` or implement your own, raw php code, for this task, right?

Comment: Did you try it with PDO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Model::chunk(200, function( $entries ) {
    // iteration of all/200
    foreach( $entries as $entry ) {
     // iteration of 200 entries 
    }
}
```

if this is still dying, its not a memory issue, more of a max execution issue. I have applications that can muster through hundreds of thousands of rows with ease.

Comment: i finally got chunking to work for me -- I was combining it with fputcsv and seeing some incorrect outputs but at long last it seems to at least NOT 500.